# Reserve CPU time for one program?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cpu-usage

### Prerequisites

I have a (physical) server running multiple (virtual) servers. There are 11 servers in total, number 0 through 9 are invoked by

```
servinit XXXXn
```

Where `XXXXn` is the port number and `n` is the server number. The other server is invoked by

```
apiinit
```

And runs on port 8080. In conclusion, there are 11 processes, 10 with the binary name `servinit` and one with `apiinit`.

### Goal

The `servinit` processes must always be responsive, in other words, the `apiinit` process must never consume all CPU time. I want to limit the total CPU time for `apiinit` to a percentage number, lets say 90, so that the `servinit` processes always have 10 percent CPU headroom to operate flawlessly.

What is the most efficient way of handling this?

### Software

The physical server runs

```
Ubuntu Desktop
Release 12.04 (precise) 64-bit
Kernel: 3.14.32-xxxx-std-ipv6-64
```

Comment: Have you tried ```renice -n 19 $API_PID```? Maybe this would be enough. I don't think it makes sense to really reserve parts of a CPU. Reserving whole CPU cores should be possible using "cgroups" -> google

Answer (score 2):

Since you run a 3.14+ Linux kernel you can easily constrain the CPU share of a running application through the SCHED_DEADLINE policy. This policy allows you to set the CPU share of an application by setting a budget and a period (the emaining is that the application is not allowed to consume more than its budget on a period of time). For example, if budget is 3msec and period is 10msec, the application can at most consume at most 30% of the CPU. In particular, the system will guarantee 3msec every 10msec.

Answer (score 1):

Solved using the optional package `cpulimit`.

Example, limiting `apiinit` to 50 percent CPU time (on a dual-core CPU):

```
sudo cpulimit -e apiinit -l 100 &
```